# Can't find web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to write some web services with clients in java. I have some code put together but i have a some errors one of the lines causing me problems is as follows:

```
static CustomerService_Service svc = new CustomerService_Service();
```

Where CustomerService_Service can't be found.

I'm using netbeans with a glassfish server installation

I have two web services and each with their own gui client.

Does anyone know why my services arent being found?

Comment: What kind of error is this? A compile-time error (your class cannot be found) or a run-time error (say, the service address could not be resolved)? We need more information to help you on this!

Comment: Its a compile time error class cannot be found

Comment: Then it has very likely nothing to do with wsdl or web-services, but is a misconfiguration of your buildpath (compile-time classpath). I am not so familiar with Netbeans, but maybe you need to add dependencies between your project.